# How to extract rows in slicing complicated condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe(series) like below

```
12a 3
4 b5
6 b7c
9 c1d
```

I would like to extract rows which contains letter 'b'(start position=3,in text)

```
4 b5
6 b7c
```

How can I extract these rows in pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`indexing with str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) and [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['12a 3','4 b5','6 b7c','9 c1d']})
print (df)
       a
0  12a 3
1   4 b5
2  6 b7c
3  9 c1d

df1 = df[df['a'].str[2:].str.contains('b')]
print (df1)
       a
1   4 b5
2  6 b7c
```

If need check only 3rd letter:

```
df1 = df[df['a'].str[2] == 'b']
print (df1)
       a
1   4 b5
2  6 b7c
```

For multiple values is possible use:

```
df1 = df[df['a'].str[2:].str.contains('[ab]')]
print (df1)
       a
0  12a 3
1   4 b5
2  6 b7c
```

And for check 3rd leter:

```
df1 = df[df['a'].str[2].isin(['a','b'])]
print (df1)
       a
0  12a 3
1   4 b5
2  6 b7c
```

---

```
df1 = df[df['a'].str[2].isin(list('ab'))]
print (df1)
       a
0  12a 3
1   4 b5
2  6 b7c
```

Comment: if I would like to extract a or b. how can I try? by using pipe?

Comment: Do you think `str.contains('[ab]')` ?